# Intuitive meaning of spectral radius of a Markov chain transition matrix?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

What is the intuitive meaning of the eigenvalues and in particular of the spectral radius of the transition matrix corresponding to a Markov chain?

Comment: As you surely know, this bounds the rate of convergence to the stationary distribution.